# Upgrade from matplotlib 2.02 _> 2.1.0 breaks polar plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, grid

I upgraded from matplotlib V2.0.2 to 2.1.0 yesterday & my plots seem to have broken as a result. I've reduced the code to the minimum needed to display the issues I'm having which are:

1. Theta label placement using ax.set_thetagrids now not working for me.
2. ax.grid not working as before.

I'd have to say that I'm new to matplotlib, but had this stuff mostly working to my satisfaction with v2.0.2.

Any ideas? Below is posted my stripped down code along with images of the output plots from a v2.02 install and v2.1.0 install. Both images were generated using the same code. Thanks for any help.

Joe

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
rect = 0,0,1,1

ax = fig.add_axes(rect, label = 'ax', polar=True)
ax.patch.set_alpha(0) #Because I'll be using this grid as an overlay on an image axis
ax.set_theta_zero_location( "N" )
ax.set_theta_direction( 1 )
thetaticks = np.arange( 0, 360, 45 )

ax.set_thetagrids( thetaticks, weight = 'bold', frac = 0.93 ) #No effect on label placement (puts them inside in v2.0.2)
ax.grid( False, 'both', color = 'k', linestyle = 'dotted', linewidth = 1.5 ) #Only applies to theta lines in v2.1.0, worked on both in 2.0.2

plt.show()
```

Output from 2.0.2:
[image: Output from 2.0.2]

Output from 2.1.0
[image: Output from 2.1.0]

Comment: A colleague found this for me this morning https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9455 Seems like its a known bug to be fixed in 2.1.1 Meanwhile any temporary solution would be appreciated.